# CSS/JS keep DIV hidden as default and open on click

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple emoji picker and the ballon remains open as default when the page is refreshed, I can't find a way how to keep it close and only open the ballon when pressing a button.

HTML

```
<div class="container">                                                                            
      <div class="emoji-btn open"><img src='images/smileys.png' title='Smileys'>
       <!--this is the div I want to keep hidden till I click the button > -->  <div class="emoji-popup">
            <div class="emoji-wrapper"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
emojibtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   this.classList.toggle("open");
});
document.body.addEventListener("click", function () {
   emojibtn.classList.remove("open");
});
```

CSS

```
.emoji-popup {
   position: absolute;
   top: -140px;
   left: 10px;
   height: 130px;
   width: 194px;
   background: #999;
   border-radius: 2px;
   text-align: left;
   overflow-y: auto;
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
   transition: all 0.25s;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.emoji-wrapper {
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 10px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.emoji-popup .emoji-img {
   margin: auto;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.emoji-popup .emoji-img:hover {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: I'd say it's because of the class `open` that you have on the second `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property `display: none;` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), `visibility: hidden`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) or `opacity: 0;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity). Then  onClick you can add the class *open* with the properties `display: block` (if it's a div), `visibility: visible` or `opacity: 1`.

Comment: I have tried with disaplay, visibility and opacity but no luck, how exacly can I add the onClick class to display? I'm know next to nothing about javascript.